# How can I add the SD Card Copier Accessory if it is missing from my Rasbian install?

Tags: raspbian

How can I add the SD Card Copier Accessory if it is missing from my Rasbian installation?

Comment: IIRC package name is `piclone`. Use normal 'apt' install procedures. Probably only available in Buster